# How to connect from STS(spring tool suite) to database(oracle)

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I am new at spring. I am trying to build my first web service, and I would like to connect to a database, get data, and return it as a JSON.

I use the spring example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service and I change it a bit, so I can get a war file.

My server that war file will deploy is Wildfly 8.2.0.

I want to connect to oracle 11g database and run SQL queries. Can you help me?

My code is posted below.

[My project format in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ8yQ.png)

Application.java:

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}


}
```

Greeting.java:

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

private final long id;
private final String content;

public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

GreetingController.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class GreetingController {


private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();


@RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Greeting> greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name,
                               @RequestParam(value="content", defaultValue="World") String content,HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Greeting> list_greet = new ArrayList<Greeting>();
    list_greet.add(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                String.format(template, name)));
    list_greet.add(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                String.format(template, content)));
    list_greet.add(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                String.format(template, name)));
    list_greet.add(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                String.format(template, name)));
    //to have webservice work,beacause cors cut it out.
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");


    return list_greet;
}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use several different ways to archive your objective, for example:

- [Follow this official doc and use Spring with jpa directly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/marx-oepe-spring-095718.html)
- [This one  just adapted to spring-boot](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/) in combination with [official spring jpa example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa)